# ntpd does not properly update drift by itself

Tags: ntpd

I am using `ntpsec` of Debian unstable. In my log I saw the following:

```
Mai 22 11:48:34 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.442261
Mai 22 11:55:06 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.524066
Mai 22 12:03:00 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.702944
Mai 22 12:08:34 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.517894
Mai 22 12:17:38 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.434055
Mai 22 12:24:07 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.084220
Mai 22 12:32:29 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.562280
Mai 22 12:38:38 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.211420
Mai 22 12:43:49 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.185642
Mai 22 12:48:58 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.796154
Mai 22 12:54:43 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 1.331323
Mai 22 13:00:21 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.849190
```

And this is not just today, it goes on like that for days. So apparently, `ntpd` does not properly fix the system clock drift. In `/var/lib/ntpsec/ntp.drift` there is always:

```
500.000000
```

What I have tried now:

- disabled CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC, so the kernel doesn't automatically update the RTC. A few hours later, I ran `hwclock -w --update-drift` to get at least a better accuracy when reading the RTC. It set the drift factor to 0.78 seconds/day.
- after that, I ran `adjtimexconfig` to fix the system clock (something that `ntpd` should have done). It said:

  ```
  Comparing clocks (this will take 70 sec)...done.
  Adjusting system time by 275,531 sec/day to agree with CMOS clock...done.
  ```

The result seems to be that `ntpd` has to step the time a lot less now:

```
Mai 22 14:24:20 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.234963
Mai 22 14:30:30 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.145163
```

Good. But why doesn't `ntpd` do that by itself? 0.2sec/6min still seems way too inexact, so I guess I'll have to repeat that process a few more times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, your OS clock is being *very* inaccurate. Normally `ntpd` would keep it in correct time by *slewing* it, i.e. telling a slow clock to "speed up" to make it catch up with real time, only adjusting the speed of the clock to match real time when it is actually in sync with the real time, and likewise slowing down the clock if it's being too fast.

But for your OS clock, this adjustment seems to be insufficient: the error is so great that `ntpd` must resort to step adjustments, essentially resetting the system clock to correct time every few minutes. If you want accurate timekeeping for databases and the like, step adjustments should be avoided completely. You should **not** be happy with any non-zero amount of step adjustments.

Fortunately the error seem to be always in the same direction, so it might be a systematic error that can be adjusted out.

**Note:** if this is a virtual machine, the time drift might be caused by the virtualization host running in a high load, and "stealing time" from idle VMs to run the busy ones. If this is the case, check with the virtualization host administrator first for recommended ways to fix the timekeeping: there might be a "paravirtualized clock" option that will let the VM essentially use the host's clock for timekeeping, or other solutions recommended by the host OS/hypervisor vendor. Just make sure the virtualization host does not fiddle with the VM's clock if you are trying to use NTP synchronization: it's one or the other, not both!

Note that `hwclock -w --update-drift` will estimate the drift of the battery-backed RTC clock by comparing it to the OS clock, which in your case is already known to be quite inaccurate. So you will be adjusting a possibly-good clock to match a known-bad one, which does not sound like a good idea.

`adjtimexconfig` on the other hand assumes the battery-backed RTC is correct and adjusts the parameters of the OS clock to match it. If you have access to a known-good NTP timesource, you should instead use `adjtimex --host <NTP server>` to compare the OS clock directly to the NTP server (stopping `ntpd` while you do that), and then use `adjtimex -p` to view the resulting `frequency` and `tick` values.

Alternatively, you could just use `adjtimex -p` to see what `frequency` offset value has been set by `ntpd`. `ntpd` will only adjust the `frequency` value; it won't touch the `tick` setting at all.

If you find the frequency offset value has gone all the way to either end of the scale at +/-32768000, you should adjust the `tick` value manually, then repeat the process.

(If `frequency` goes to or near the maximum positive value, the tool is trying to speed up the clock and fails to speed it up enough as it runs out of adjustment range. To fix that, increase the `tick` value. If `frequency` goes to or near the negative limit, decrease the `tick` value.)

Once you find a `tick` value that lets the frequency offset value stay at relatively
near the middle of the scale (say, +/- 5000000 or so), then `ntpd` should have a much better chance at keeping the clock in sync by tweaking the frequency offset value as needed. You should edit the tick value manually into `/etc/default/adjtimexconfig` and ensure that the `adjtimex.service` gets executed successfully at boot: it runs before `ntpd` is started, and so sets the OS clock into "correct gear" before `ntpd` starts acting as a "cruise control" for it.

Once you get the OS clock under control, so that `ntpd` will keep in a synchronized state (`ntpq -np` will display an asterisk in the first column) and there are no log messages about step adjustments other than maybe once at boot time, then you can use `hwclock -w --update-drift` to estimate the drift rate of the RTC clock. The end result should be a system that keeps as good time as reasonably achievable whether it's powered on or not.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer! Thanks a lot, that explains some of the things I wasn't clear about. Yes, it is my computer, no VM. And yes, the RTC is already quite bad, it is off by a minute per month or so. I didn't pay attention yet, but now I will.

`adjtimex -h` seems like the jewel in your answer, but it doesn't work for me: `ntpdate: -p is no longer supported. Illegal option -d. cannot understand ntpdate output` is what it says.

Comment: I cannot quite confirm your `tick` interpretation: if I set it to 9900, time will be stepped by 2.6, if I set it to 10100, time will be stepped by -2.8. So it seems to me that higher `tick` values make the clock go faster.

Comment: Yup, after a night of sleep it looks like I got it backwards. Fixed. Anyway, monitor the `adjtimex -p`values occasionally over a few days as `ntpd` adjusts the clock, and if it seems the frequency offset still gets large (positive or negative), then adjust the tick value until the frequency offset stays in the center part of its range.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am finally truly happy with the situation! I updated my own answer with the explanations from what I learned from you :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh... maybe `adjtimexconfig` was actually the answer?! Whatever the reason, what I did above finally made `ntpd` write updates to `/var/lib/ntpsec/ntp.drift`; and in the last 60 minutes I only got two messages:

```
Mai 22 15:59:45 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.241656
Mai 22 16:31:47 services ntpd[13428]: CLOCK: time stepped by 0.532398
```

I guess I am happy with that for now.

EDIT: Thanks to telcoM, I think I now have all the answers and the solution. First, the explanation for what happened: 10000 is apparently the initial `tick`. On my system, this is way too slow. So `ntpd` had to constantly step the time. `ntp` does not adjust the `tick`, only the fine-grained adjustment `frequency`, so it is limited and powerless if `tick` is way off.

When I used `adjtimexconfig`, it fixed the `tick`, but only according to my also inaccurate RTC. It set `tick` to 10031, which is still significantly too low, so `ntpd` still had to jump the time. And that is the reason `/var/lib/ntpsec/ntp.drift` stayed at 500.000000 (and therefore `ntpd` seemed to never update it), which is equivalent to a frequency of 32768000 (drift*65536).

Now I used `adjtimex -t 10038` to fix the `tick` and suddenly I don't see any `CLOCK: time stepped` messages anymore. `ntpd` is currently using `frequency: -10025033`, so I guess I could do with 10037 as well.

Comment: Looks like you got it under control, then. I'd recommend noting down the tick value somewhere, like perhaps the inside cover of the motherboard's manual: "Slow clock, needs `adjtimex` with tick value of approx. 10037 to keep correct time in Linux." That way you won't have to start from scratch if you ever have to reinstall the OS. If you can let the system run continuously for a few days, and `ntpd` keeps in sync, you should start seeing a meaningful value in `ntp.drift` now as the worst part of the systematic error is cancelled out by the tick adjustment.